# Como multiplicar estructura HTML por cada ciclo del for?

Tags: javascript, select, javascript-objeto, html-select, javascript-metodo

Estoy aprendiendo .Js y estoy tratando de cargar un array en un select. Paso a explicar...

Tengo un formulario con 3 select, el primero de estos 3 tiene una serie de opciones con marca de vehículos, el 2do quiero cargarlo dinámicamente con un array que contiene los modelos de la marca seleccionada y el 3ero cargarlo dinámicamente con las versiones del modelo seleccionado.

El problema radica en que tengo un switch donde depende la selección del primer select llama a una función, la cual con un for recorre el array y inserta el código html con innertHTML.

el switch funciona perfecto, pero la función solo me carga el ultimo valor del array. utilice un console.log para ver que genera el for, el for recorre bien el array pero no logro encontrar como multiplicar el código html del innertHTML por cada ciclo, lo que pasa es que se sobre escribe y me muestra el ultimo valor en el select.

Dejo el código para ver que es lo que hago mal, desde ya muchas gracias a todos por su aporte!

```
let Smarca = document.getElementById('select-marca');
let Smodelo = document.getElementById('select-modelo');
let Sversion = document.getElementById('select-version');

function CargarSelect (a){
    for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        Smodelo.innerHTML = `<option value="${i}">${a[i]}</option>`;
        console.log (`${i} ---> ${a[i]}`);
    }
}

Smarca.onchange = () =>{
    let x = Smarca.value;
    switch (x){
        case "0":
            CargarSelect(modelosCH);
            break;
        case "1":
            CargarSelect(modelosCI);
            break;
        case "2":
            CargarSelect(modelosFI);
        case 3:
            CargarSelect(modelosDG);
            break;
        case "4":
            CargarSelect(modelosFO);
            break;
        case 5:
            CargarSelect(modelosPE);
            break;
        case 6:
            CargarSelect(modelosPE);
            break;
        case 7:
            CargarSelect(modelosRE);
            break;
        case 8:
            CargarSelect(modelosVW);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

innerHTML lo que hace, es reemplazar el HTML que tienes por uno nuevo, en tu caso, se corren todos los innerHTML, pero al ser el último que se corre el de la última posición del arreglo, te reemplaza todos en cada iteración, y al final deja el último como el único que hay. La solución es utilizar un += en lugar de un = cuando haces el innerHTML, tu función cargarSelect quedaría algo así

```js
function CargarSelect (a){
    for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        Smodelo.innerHTML += `<option value="${i}">${a[i]}</option>`;
        console.log (`${i} ---> ${a[i]}`);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfecta tu respuesta, soluciono el problema de que solo me dejaba la ultima opción,  pero ahora cuando cambio el valor del primer select me agrega las opciones de la primer selección y del cambio de valor. Me podrías orientar como eliminar los valores anterior para cargar los nuevos y que no sumen? Gracias!

Comment: Lo solucione gracias!